# Building QT app in Nucleus using cygwin

Tags: qt, arm, rtos

Our team has installed ReadyStart-arm for Nucleus with QT plugin.
However I could not find the qt libraries present in the same.
The qt directory containing qt-everywhere tar file and qt patch is outside the nucleus RTOS.

In case I want to build exe for Nucleus RTOS with QT app through cygwin (instead of Sourcery codebench), how can I proceed?

Comment: Sorry for typo in heading: Building QT app in Nucleus through cygwin

Comment: Why do you need or expect the libraries to be withing the RTOS directory?  Unpack the TAR file wherever you need it and configure your project, makefile or whatever to access it wherever it is.

Comment: Yep..Thanks a lot